# What is adaptive spinning w.r.t lock acquisition?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

One of the four major changes brought to java 6 with regards to improving the performance of intrinsic locks is *Adapative Spinning* technique. What exactly is adaptive spinning? Is it a combination of [spinlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) and mutex lock? Can someone explain in an easy to understand way the usefulness of this strategy which by default is available from JDK6 onwards.

Comment: [Oracle blog](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.3)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What exactly is adaptive spinning?

To quote from this [Java 6 performance page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.3):

> Adaptive spinning is an optimization technique where a two-phase spin-then-block strategy is used by threads attempting a contended synchronized enter operation. This technique enables threads to avoid undesirable effects that impact performance such as context switching and repopulation of [Translation Lookaside Buffers (TLBs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer). It is “adaptive" because the duration of the spin is determined by policy decisions based on factors such as the rate of success and/or failure of recent spin attempts on the same monitor and the state of the current lock owner.

So threads initially attempt to spin a couple of times trying to acquire a lock before actually blocking.  Then in the future it uses previous success/fail metrics to adaptively determine whether it should try spinning or blocking.  Spinning wastes CPU time while blocking may cause a context switch and the thread may wait for a longer amount of time than necessary.  The goal is trying to optimize both of these issues based on past behavior.

For more details, the performance doc references this presentation entitled [Synchronization in Java SE 6 (HotSpot)](http://fliphtml5.com/tzor/bqxz) by Dave Dice.  The first slide is titled "Contended costs (scalability + latency)":

- Context switching is extremely expensive
- Unbounded spinning is unacceptable
- Address via adaptive spinning

Later in the presentation there is the slide entitled "Adaptive Spinning":

- Spin-then-block strategy

  - Try to avoid context switch by spinning on [multi-processor] systems
- Spin duration

  - Maintained per-monitor
  - varies based on recent history of spin success/failure ratio
- Adapts to system load, parallelism, application modality
- [multi-processor]-polite spinning
- Avoid spinning in futile conditions (owner is blocked)

Interesting stuff.

Comment: For people interested in the details, the interesting parts in the code (for HotSpot that is) are in objectMonitor.cpp. It has actually a very good explanation of adaptive spinning in a long comment (search for "Adaptive Spinning Support") there. Was tempted to just post the whole comment but not sure how useful that would be as a whole answer, so this is the compromise. The actual code is in `ObjectMonitor::TrySpin_VaryDuration` for people interested in the gory details such as reducing bus traffic for coherency, etc.

Comment: @Gray Can you please comment on the *repopulation of Translation Lookaside Buffers (TLBs)*? What does this mean?

Comment: @Gray one more follow up related to this line : *Try to avoid context switch by spinning on **MP** systems*. What does *MP* mean?

Comment: MP is multiprocessors @Geek.

Comment: TLB's are involved with memory cacheing @Geek: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer